# How to know if user is online?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-messaging, whatsapp

I am building a texting app and I want to have a feature like WhatsApp, where one user can know whether different users are online or not. I have used Firebase for the texting feature, storing message in realtime database and listening for messages in ChildEventListener.

Comment: The Firebase docs on "Managing Presence" may be useful: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-presence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a field in firebase name status or something like this. Then if user come online, set the value 1, and if goes offline, set the value 0.

So, you will get info of a user if he or she is offline or online.

Answer (score 1):

In you database you could add a path where you add user objects with a parameter for the online status.  You would have to create a new one when a new account is created and update the online status everytime a user goes online/offline. For identification which object you have to update, you should use the Users unique ID so that should probably be stored there as well....

Comment: How would you update the status if the user is offline? i.e. they have no internet connection, so there is no way to transmit this knowledge